# How to build ASCII hex dump from a number of dec values?

Tags: linux, bash, hex, hexdump

I want to analyse some dec\hex strings (ethernet headers) in Wireshark. It only can open ASCII hex dump according to manual. Is there some software or a piece of code that can parse strings with hex values (as is, not dump it) and order it to hex dump format?

Comment: *"... that can parse strings with hex values ..."* - a bit confused. u already have hex text, then how would u like it to be parsed?

Comment: Do you have any data sample?

Answer (score 0):

The program xxd has the ability to "revert" hex values from a wide variety of dumps back into binary data.

```
marshall@likon:[~/Hack]: cat hello
hello
how are you
marshall@likon:[~/Hack]: xxd -i < hello > blah
marshall@likon:[~/Hack]: cat blah 
  0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x0a, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x20, 0x61, 0x72,
  0x65, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x0a
marshall@likon:[~/Hack]: xxd -ps -r < blah > regen
marshall@likon:[~/Hack]: cat regen 
hello
how are you
```

But the only way to know for sure if it'll do it is to have a data sample, or try it.